# search lan in resolv.conf

Tags: lan, resolv.conf

On 12.04 server, I have static NIC config, but I want to remove lan from the dns search path, or resolv.conf. This is auto-generated as we know. I don't want it to search anything, except for what I tell it in the interfaces file. Why does it include .lan in the search path? Mind boggling.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
search lan local
```

Above, I only want "search local" (or nothing even!) Below, i tried to specify local, in the hope that lan would go away. Not so.

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.2.28
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.2.2
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
dns-domain local
dns-search local

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.0.0.28
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
dns-domain local
dns-search local
```

Comment: Try removing the lines dns-domain and dns-search.

Comment: I've tried all this. I still end up with "search lan".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in comments, uninstalling resolvconf (as in the package with that name) stops ubuntu doing it's silly own things.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` to recreate the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf.

Make sure that `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` is empty of `domain` and `search` options.

You can omit the `dns-domain` options from `/etc/network/interfaces`. They are superfluous.

Comment: the symlink is there. This is not what this is about.

Comment: name resolution works as such. base is 0 bytes, and one of my VMs now does not have the problem (it's been off for a day, but no changes). I am spooked out. Maybe I can uninstall resolvconf. I don't get the point of having it, other than being a pita.

Comment: Uninstalled. Badness gone. I'm in control again. Thank goodness.

Comment: Background: The "lan" search domain must have been coming from somewhere. If resolvconf was writing the contents of /etc/resolv.conf (which it presumably *was* doing if /etc/resolv.conf was a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf which is what resolvconf actually writes) then it "domain lan" or "search lan" must have been either in /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base or in some file in /run/resolvconf/interface/. Files are normally only present in the latter directory after being put there by a "resolvconf -a".

Comment: If the `base` file was empty and nothing has been customized then I would conclude that something has run `resolvconf -a`. 1. Are you using NetworkManager in `[ifupdown] managed=false` mode? If so then look for `lan` in the `Additional search domains` field.

Comment: 2. `lan` sounds like the domain name that a modemrouter's DHCP server would be configured to use when unboxed. Is it possible that you configured the interface using a DHCP client and then you killed that client and reconfigured the interface as `iface eth0 inet static` and haven't rebooted since then? If so then there could be a stale file in /run/resolvconf/interface/ containing `domain lan` or `search lan`. Such stale files get deleted on reboot. To avoid ending up with such stale files, use the prescribed methods for stopping clients (e.g., `dhclient -r`) rather than `kill -9`.